# How to override css child class property using ng-style in AngularJS?

Tags: css, angularjs, html

I want to override css child class property using ng-style in AngularJS.

For instance my code is:

```
.spin-preloader
{
        width:54px;
        -webkit-animation:mymove 1s infinite;
        -animation:mymove 1s infinite;
}

@webkit-animation mymove
{
    from  
    {
        left:0px;
    }
    to
    {
        left:80px;  
    }
}
```

I want to write html code like this:

```
<div class="spin-preloader" ng-style="-----?----" />
```

i want to override 80 px of 'to' of @webkit-animation class

Is there any way to do this? I mean what should be the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: What is the style you want to replace?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle

Answer (score 0):

You could apply your class via `ng-style` without having the `class` attribute set, so you do not need to overwrite anything:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-style="{'spin-preloader': showSpinPreloader, 'no-spin-preloader': !showSpinPreloader}"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
app.controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope) {
    // do some magic here to determine whether which CSS class to apply
    $scope.showSpinPreloader = true;
});
```

Comment: yes i need to know the proper syntax of overriding 80 px of 'to'propert in webkit-animation class

Comment: Do you want to override the value just once? If so, creating a new CSS class with a new animation `mymove2` with a different left value could do the trick. In your angular controller you decide which class to apply

Comment: hi actually i want to make this parametrised or dynamic which cannot be done in a css ...so i want to override this in a html using ng-style

Comment: I guess it is not possible to directly modify `webkit-animation` via inline styles. But you could restructure your HTML and maybe apply the wisdom of this tutorial (https://css-tricks.com/animate-to-an-inline-style/) to achieve your goal.